# How to find all enhancements in SAP system?

Tags: abap

I need to prepare a document which includes all enhancements implemented in the SAP system of the company, what are all steps that I have to go through?

Answer (score 3):

Another more comprehensive way to find all the enhancements is to (re)use the best practices.

A wonderful tool called ABAP Exit Ray Eye was developed [yet in 2009](https://code.google.com/archive/p/abapexitrayeye/) and though it is a bit forgotten now, it is still does the job.

Having different criteria

[image]

it can show you currently implemented enhancements in a very nifty and user-friendly way:

[image]

The source code of this tool can be grabbed in archive from [Github repo](https://github.com/OlivieriAndrea/ABAPexitrayeye/releases) and is installable by SAPLink.

Answer (score 2):

Try running SAP Standard program `SNIF` in se38. It might help. For more information refer to this blog post. https://blogs.sap.com/2012/04/16/lets-find-enhancements/

Comment: The problem is that SNIF does not search enhancements per se (ENHO objects) but only old types of exits. And even them it searches very bad, I tried it in my overcustomized system (30000+ enhancements), and it found almost nothing

Answer (score 1):

All the enhancements reside in `ENHINCINX` table and can be searched by package like this:

```
PARAMETERS p_pack TYPE devclass.

"Accept wildcards for package
p_pack = COND #( WHEN p_pack IS INITIAL THEN '%' ELSE replace( val = p_pack sub = `*` with = `%` occ = 0 ) ).

SELECT e~*
  FROM enhincinx AS e
 INNER JOIN tadir AS t
    ON 'R3TR' = t~pgmid
   AND 'ENHO' = t~object
   AND e~enhname = t~obj_name
 WHERE t~devclass LIKE @p_pack
  INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_enhincinx).


LOOP AT lt_enhincinx ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_enhincinx>).
 WRITE: / |{ <ls_enhincinx>-programname } / { <ls_enhincinx>-enhname }:|.
ENDLOOP.
```